# Ignore obsolete field when deserializing

Tags: c#, serialization, field, versioning, obsolete

I have been searching all day for a way to achieve this without result...

I am trying to deserialize an object. When I serialized it, I had a bool called (let's say) obsoleteBool. In the new version of the class I removed this bool, and I now have an error when deserializing (Field "obsoleteBool" not found).

It is very easy to add new fields between an old and a new version of a class. Even without using the [OptionalField] attribute... but how can I manage the removal of a field between an old and new version of a class?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Implementing ISerializable. It'll take time and effort but you'll have much more control (and you can - roughly - manage versioning).

Comment: What are you serializing it with?

Comment: I want my class to be extended by users. From what I understood, using ISerializable will require them to manage the serialization of the new variables they will create. When I use the [Serializable] attribute, they can create new variable without doing anything else for it to be saved.

@ahruss: I am serializing with a BinaryFormatter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 possible solutions:

- The simplest: Add the old Field to the New Version og the class
- Custom code: Implement a custom deserializer
- Extra work: Write a Conversion program that goes through all the serialized classes, that reads them With the old format and reserializes them With the New class definition.

In terms of business value the first option is probably preferable.

Comment: Because users will extend my class and will probably iterate a lot between serialization, I'd like the cleanest solution possible. Keeping the obsolete field could quickly end up with a code extremely messy, not even talking about people who may choose to not rename a variable because of that and end up with misfitting name or similar issues.
Will a custom serializer be able to automatically consider the new fields created by users? About the conversion program, how will I even be able to open the classes to convert if I have my "missing field" error message when I try?

Comment: @RyanPergent with ISerializable you may manage fields in derived classes too (as BinaryFormatter does). Of course it's not best solution but you can do it (through Reflection). To do conversion you have to deploy both versions (with and without extra field), deserialize in one AppDomain, move deserialized data to new format in a second AppDomain. Pretty hard. Whole point IMO is that serialization IS NOT the tool to use for data file (with versioning). It's useful for many things but not this (because after few versions it'll make your code a messy and if you ever change hierarchy...)

Comment: I am trying to implement the ISerializable method right now. The only inconvenience is that I need to have a constructor with the SerializationInfo and StreamingContext in all the classes inheriting from the default one (I have plenty). But that is a minor defect compared to not being able to delete variables. However, I am facing another issue: I am using Reflection to get and save all the fields, but I need to get only the [Serializable] ones. BindingFlags do not seem to offer such a filtering... Does someone know how I can filter my fields in such a manner?

Comment: I managed to filter them out using IsNotSerialized from System.Reflection.FieldInfo :) Thanks a lot for your help guys, I think I will manage to achieve what I want now.